# Data is not getting printed in generated pdf report in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to generate a very simple report in nodejs using the api [fluentreports](https://github.com/NathanaelA/fluentreports). Data is coming from mysql db. But, data is not being printed in the generated pdf file. Though header and footer is being printed. It seems .data(results) is not being executed. Any suggestion is much appreciated. There is no error produced in the console. Here is the code:

```
 app.post('/adminreport', function(req,res){
  var reportDate = req.body.report_Date;

  console.log("Report Date : " + reportDate);

    connection.connect(function(err){
     if(err){
       console.log('Error connecting to Db');
       return;
     }
     console.log('Connection established');
   });

   connection.query('SELECT id, fName, lName, pickUpDate FROM reservations_db WHERE pickUpDate = ?', [reportDate], function(err, results, fields){
     if (!err) 
     {
      //res.sendStatus(200).json({status:"ok"});

      console.log('The result is generated successfully!');
      console.log(results);
      //console.log(fields);

    var headerFunction = function(Report) {
      Report.print("Report By Date", {fontSize: 22, bold: true, underline:true, align: "center"});
      Report.newLine(2);
    };

    var footerFunction = function(Report) {
        Report.line(Report.currentX(), Report.maxY()-18, Report.maxX(), Report.maxY()-18);
        Report.pageNumber({text: "Page {0} of {1}", footer: true, align: "right"});
        Report.print("Report printed: "+ reportDate, {y: Report.maxY()-14, align: "left"});
    };
    //var res = function(Report) { 
    //    Report.print(results);
    //};


    var rpt = new Report("report_js.pdf")
        .margins(20)                                 // Change the Margins to 20 pixels                                  // Add Data
        .pageHeader(headerFunction)                  // Add a header
        .data(results)                               // Add Data
        .pageFooter(footerFunction)                  // Add a footer
        .render();         
      }

     else 
     {
     console.log('Error while performing persistence!'); 
     } 
    });
```

This is the generated pdf file:

[image]

Here is the console.log :

```
Report Date : 12/09/2016
Connection established
The result is generated successfully!
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 3,
    fName: 'ffree',
    lName: 'dgtrh',
    pickUpDate: '12/09/2016' } ]
[object Object]
It is working!
```

Comment: What `console.logs` are showing? Are there any errors being outputted? It would be helpful to know which lines of code are being executed, and which ones are not being executed.

Comment: @therobinkim,  It seems .data(results) is not being executed. There is no error produced in the console. I added the console.log in the question.

Comment: See the answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I actually missed one more method to call .detail(). Here is the code for future users:

```
app.post('/adminreport', function(req,res){
  var reportDate = req.body.report_Date;

  console.log("Report Date : " + reportDate);

    connection.connect(function(err){
     if(err){
       console.log('Error connecting to Db');
       return;
     }
     console.log('Connection established');
   });

   connection.query('SELECT id, fName, lName, pickUpDate FROM reservations_db WHERE pickUpDate = ?', 
    [reportDate], function(err, results, fields){
     if (!err) 
     {
      //res.sendStatus(200).json({status:"ok"});

      console.log('The result is generated successfully!');
      console.log(results);
      //console.log(fields);

    var headerFunction = function(Report) {
      Report.print("Report By Date", {fontSize: 22, bold: true, underline:true, align: "center"});
      Report.newLine(2);
      Report.fontBold();
      Report.band([
    {data: 'ID#', width: 50, align: 3, zborder:{left:1, right: 1, top: 0, bottom: 1}},
    {data: 'First Name', width: 100, align: 3, zborder:{left:1, right: 1, top: 0, bottom: 1}},
    {data: 'Last Name', width: 100, align: 3, zborder:{left:1, right: 1, top: 0, bottom: 1}},
    {data: 'PickUp Date', width: 100, align: 3, zborder:{left:1, right: 1, top: 0, bottom: 1}}
  ], {border:1, width: 0, wrap: 1} );
     Report.fontNormal();
    };

    var reportdetail = function ( Report, data ) {
    Report.band( [
        {data: data.id, width: 50, align: 3, zborder:{left:1, right: 1, top: 0, bottom: 1}},
        {data: data.fName, width: 100, align: 3, zborder:{left:1, right: 1, top: 0, bottom: 1}},
        {data: data.lName, width: 100, align: 3, zborder:{left:1, right: 1, top: 0, bottom: 1}},
        {data: data.pickUpDate, width: 100, align: 3, zborder:{left:1, right: 1, top: 0, bottom: 1}}
    ], {border:1, width: 0, wrap: 1} );
  };

    var footerFunction = function(Report) {
        Report.line(Report.currentX(), Report.maxY()-18, Report.maxX(), Report.maxY()-18);
        Report.pageNumber({text: "Page {0} of {1}", footer: true, align: "right"});
        Report.print("Report printed: "+ reportDate, {y: Report.maxY()-14, align: "left"});
    };
    //var res = function(Report) { 
    //    Report.print(results);
    //};

    var rpt = new Report("report_js.pdf")
        .margins(20)                                 // Change the Margins to 20 pixels                                  // Add Data
        .pageHeader(headerFunction)                  // Add a header
        .data(results)                               // Add Data
        .detail(reportdetail)
        .pageFooter(footerFunction)                  // Add a footer        
        .render();         
      }

     else 
     {
     console.log('Error while performing persistence!'); 
     } 
    });

   connection.end(function(err) {
       console.log('It is working!');
    }); 

  //res.redirect('/admin');
});
```